# Importing modules with dot in python

Tags: python, python-import

I have read https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports but I have not found explicit confirmation.

Assuming the following structure of a package:

```
|-package1
|--|__init__.py
│--|module.py
```

I want to import `module.py` inside `__init__.py`.

I wonder if there is any semantic difference between:

```
from . import module
```

and

```
from .module import *
```

assuming that I want to import everything inside `module.py` every time `package` is loaded.

Comment: Have you tried? Did it make a difference?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *semantic* difference (because the two statements are obviously semantically different), but if you mean if they have any different effects on how you proceed to use the library from there on, then yes, because your namespace will be different, i.e. how you reference different objects from `module`.

Comment: @mapf The two statements are obviously _syntactically_ different. I was asking if they are also different _semantically_. The answer is yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The big difference between these two things is that the first case keeps the names namespaced in `module` the second example imports all the names from `module` into the current namespace.

Suppose `module.py` defines a function `foo`.

```py
from . import module
module.foo()
```

vs.

```py
from .module import *
foo()
```

But as far as how the import system goes about loading the module/package, nothing changes. Both import statements address exactly the same module and only that module. How you access the imported module by name is affected by the import statement as shown above.

Also PEP8 is just a style guide. [PEP328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) will tell you more about relative imports